# Difference between IwGx, Iw2D and s3e

Tags: c++, airplay, marmalade

What is the main difference between `IwGx`, `Iw2D` and `s3e` api in `marmalade`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

s3e provides a core set of APIs that allow for cross platform development.
IwGx is a renderer abstraction layer providing efficient access to the software renderer and Open GL.
Iw2D is a simple 2D drawing API to hide some complexities of IwGx.

Comment: So they are related with each other too? If yes can you tell me how? I mean when can I use one over other?

Comment: Iw2d is built on top of IwGx. IwGx is built on top of s3e.

If you are doing a simple 2d application/game, use Iw2D. For 3D, go for IwGx.